# animate div movement relative to another div size change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Having an issue making this animation work for me.

Essentially I have a vertical scrolling page with several div elements that vary in size based on the content being displayed.  What's happening is that as these size changes occur the other elements are jumping abruptly based.  I'd like to make these a bit more smooth.

This is actually part of a massive project (angular) so I can't bring in any external libraries.  I've created a jfiddle which illustrates the problem.

```
$('.close').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().height(0);
    $(this).parent().parent().slideUp(500);// in case if you want to move the second div up.

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zberQ/5/

So to summarize, the issue is actually not with the element who's height is changing.  The issue is with the elements below it which are instantly jumping up or down in response to this height change.

Comment: Is it like this in "all" browsers?

Comment: Yes - maybe jump is not the best word, but if the div above it increases by 300 pixels, everything under it will instantly be pushed down 300 pixels.

Comment: I removed a .parent() and it seems smoother. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/zberQ/17/ Just jumps for that margin between divs.

Comment: How about just a slideUp then? http://jsfiddle.net/zberQ/20/. Edit - I now see that's been posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i first removed the line $(this).parent().parent().height(0); - not sure if u need it or not.

then in the remaining i removed a .parent and it seems smoother, just the margin jump.

fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/zberQ/17/

js

```
$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp(400);
});
```

css (stripped down)

```
.publication1 {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

.publication2 {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}

.publication3 {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```